# Update/delete queries cannot be typed

Tags: java, jpa

I want to implement update query in JPA. I tried this:

```
public void updateTransactionStatus(String uniqueId, String type, String status) throws Exception {

        String hql = "update " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName()
                + " e SET e.status = :status WHERE e.unique_id = :unique_id AND e.type = :type";
        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactions> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, PaymentTransactions.class).setParameter("status", status).setParameter("unique_id", uniqueId).setParameter("type", type);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

But I get `Update/delete queries cannot be typed`. What is the proper wya to implement this?> I tried to replace TypedQuery with Query but I get `The type Query is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <PaymentTransactions>`

Comment: why would you need to type an update query?

Comment: What solution can you propose?

Comment: you have unique_id. is this the primary key? OR do unique_id + type can distinguish max one entry?

Comment: well I can fist select the query, if there is a request I can update it with update query?

Comment: An update query returns how many objects were updated. End of. There is never a need to provide a "type", since that simply determines what is returned

Answer (score 0):

In general if you do not need to you should avoid using batch updates with JPA unless they are triggered from within a `REQUIRES_NEW` marked transaction (and thats the only operation).

It seems that you need to perform an update on one unique entry so I would suggest a query followed by a modification, thats it:

```
// retrieve

PaymentTransactions paymentTransaction = 
     entityManager.createQuery("select t from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() 
          + " where e.unique_id = :unique_id AND e.type = :type "
      , PaymentTransactions.class);
      .setParameter("unique_id", uniqueId).setParameter("type", type)
      .getSingleResult();

// modify

paymentTransaction.setStatus(status);
```

Here is the place for a `TypedQuery`.

As long as your method is within a transactional context, thats all you need to do to update the entry.